# Fetch data into table using PDO result in no value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I want to fetch all the tasks related to the user into a table. However, the result is '0 results'. I did try to echo print_r($allTask), and the result is Array() 1. I don't know what is the problem because, in the incomplete database, there are several tasks, but nothing shows up when I fetch it. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you for your help

Note: I put the fetch query inside the if(isset($_POST['submit']) because I want every time the user adds the new task and click submit. The incomplete database will be updated as well to display the new task added to the table

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$owner = $_SESSION['name'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$due_date=$_POST['due_date'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$state=0;
$insertQuery="INSERT INTO incomplete (owner, title, description, due_date, time, state)
VALUES (:owner, :title, :description, :due_date, :time, :state)";
$preparedInsertStatement = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':title', $title);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':description', $description);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':due_date', $due_date);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':time', $time);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':state', $state);
$valueInsert=$preparedInsertStatement->execute();
if($valueInsert){
    echo 'Insert is done';
}
else{
    echo 'Insert is not successful';
} 
$displayQuery="SELECT * FROM incomplete where owner=':owner'";
$displayTask= $conn->prepare($displayQuery);
$displayTask->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$displayTask->execute();
$allTask=$displayTask->fetchAll();
echo print_r($allTask);
if(count($allTask) > 0)
{
  echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Due 
Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
foreach ($allTask as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["description"]."</td><td>".$row["due_date"]."</td><td>".$row["time"]."</td></tr>";
}

  }else{
      echo '0 results';
  }

 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Tip: You can just `execute([ 'owner' => $_SESSION['name'], 'title' => $_POST['title'], ... ])` and avoid the single-use variables and all the `bindValue` calls.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. These have patterns for handling form submissions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but this is a school project and I am not allowed to use any frameworks. However, do you know why the fetch result in no value?

Comment: One day schools will teach how to use PHP properly, but until then you're going to have to suffer some more apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using placeholder values be absolutely sure you haven't introduced any additional syntax. I can see `owner=':owner'` which is incorrect. The placeholder should not have quotes around it.

This should be:

```
'... owner=:owner'
```

PDO takes care of escaping. The quotes are just in the way.